# Open source web file sharing platform

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a little business and I always need to share files with my workers.
I'm looking for an open source PHP or ASP web platform that will allow me and the workers to upload and edit documents, pictures, etc...
And set different permissions for different users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend VPS with samba instead. (or a regular NAS)

The web isn't suited for the task.